# How to capture two or more groups if they match to a pattern and are the same characters?

Tags: regex, regex-group

So I have the following set of lines:

```
H23-H23
H23-H24
H23-K23
H23-K24
H23-N23
H23-N24

K23-H23
K23-H24
K23-K23
K23-K24
K23-N23
K23-N24

H24-H23
H24-H24
H24-K23
H24-K24
H24-N23
H24-N24
```

it falls under the following pattern `([FGHJKMNQUVXZ]\d{2})-([FGHJKMNQUVXZ]\d{2})` . What I am trying to get is to filter out only those lines where both groups are the same, i.e.

```
H23-H23
K23-K23
H24-H24
```

Is this possible somehow?

Currently I didn't find a way to make a relation between two capturing groups

Comment: TLDR - `([FGHJKMNQUVXZ]\d{2})-\1` - https://regex101.com/r/lHDkTr/1

Comment: Thank you, didn't know the right name for it